# How Can I call useCollection hook again with updated parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

When My Home component(image above) mounts for the first time, it gives call to the hook "useCollection" with the arguments below, Now how can I call useCollection hook again with a different set of arguments for filtering my list,

It gives error calling to a function by using onClickButon handlers as well I m not able to use "UseState" as useState does not call the above hook again.

**useCollection Hook**

```
 import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
 import { projectFirestore } from "../firebase/config";

 export const useCollections = (collection, _query, _orderBy) => {
 const [documents, setDocuments] = useState(null);
 const [error, setError] = useState(null);

 const query = useRef(_query).current;
 const orderBy = useRef(_orderBy).current;

 useEffect(() => {

    let ref = projectFirestore.collection(collection);

    if (query) {
      ref = ref.where(...query);
    }

    if (orderBy) {
      ref = ref.orderBy(...orderBy);
    }

    const unsubscribe = ref.onSnapshot(
      (snapshot) => {
        let results = [];
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id });
        });

        setDocuments(results);
        setError(null);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setError("could not fetch data");
      }
    );

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [collection, query, orderBy]);

  return { documents, error };
};
```